# Edge not showing div background image for some img src files

Tags: html, css

I have two problems with Edge browser not showing up the image.

**Issue 1:**

```
<div class="profile-pic">
</div>

.profile-pic {
    background: url(../images/profile-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

The image is showing correctly in both Edge & Chrome.
But when I change the image url to anew image, lets say, (../images/profile-bg1.jpg), Chrome updates to new image, but Edge doesn't show anything. The div is blank in Edge (even though inspecting the code in Edge show the new url.

I also tried to replace another image with the same file name *profile-bg.jpg*, but Edge still shows blank. Chrome working fine. Surprisingly, Edge is only showing the initial image file I used.

I tried clearing cache and all, but nothing works.

**Issue 2:**

```
<div class="profile">
    <img src="images/profile-bg1.jpg">
</div>

.profile {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.profile img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Again, Chrome shows the image, Edge doesn't.

Any solutions>

Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing about your code that looks wrong. I can't see why it wouldn't work in Edge. And indeed, I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/su71dztu/) example using your code, but with a different image, and it works fine. As I would expect.